# How to limit tmux to create at most 10 windows for a session?

Tags: tmux

GNU screen has `maxwin` and I use `maxwin 10` since we only have digits 0~9. I searched tmux man page and failed to find the equivalent. So how can I limit the max number of windows for a tmux session?

Comment: can I ask, why do you want to do this?

Comment: sometimes i just repeat `<c-b> c` to create more windows until i have 10. without the limit i myself must count how many windows i have already created. with the limit i can just blindly repeat `<c-b> c` until no new windows are created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to come up with a workaround <sup>(tested with tmux v3.3a)</sup> —

Since most of the time I create new windows with `<c-b> c` I redefined the `c` binding:

```
bind  c  if '[ "#{session_windows}" -lt 10 ]' \
            'new-window' 'display "!! too many windows" '
```

Comment: Another alternative is to just add enough `neww` commands to your `tmux.conf` to open 10 windows - you'll always have ten and no need to open any more unless you close one.  Works for me.  Actually, I have those in a secondary conf file (~/.tmux/main-session) and have `bind P source-file ~/.tmux/main.session` to load it.  I also have an alternate session "profile" with `bind O source-file ~/.tmux/other.session`. Then I just have to run `tmux` and type ^KP to load my main session or ^KO for the alternate (I have `set-option -g prefix C-k` because I use ^A in bash all the time but rarely use ^K)

Comment: I also use `rename-window` for each `new-window` in my "*.session" files so that each tmux window has a useful name (e.g. one is called "mutt", and others are named for various other tasks or hostnames - e.g. so I always know, for example, that ^K5 will take me to my ssh session for host "X" and ^K6 will take me to my ssh session to host "Y".   I do the same kind of naming for tabs in my terminal emulator (which is why I never use escape codes in PS1 etc to change the terminal/tab title, I want them to stay as whatever I set them to)

Comment: @cas thanks for sharing.

Comment: No problem. Hope it's of some use.  BTW, i just remembered that the default prefix in tmux is ^B, not ^A.  GNU screen uses ^A as the prefix - I changed it to ^K in screen and kept doing the same in tmux because I was used to it, it's hard to change long entrenched habits and not really any good reason to do so in this particular case.

Comment: i use different prefix for tmux (`c-q`) and screen (`c-a`) because i run screen from within tmux (tmux sessions on local host and screen sessions on remote servers). i used to run nested screen sessions but it has some issues. local tmux + remote screen works perfectly for me.